# Do homeomorphic sets have to be in the same dimension?

Tags: general-topology

For example, if we have sets $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $G=[0,1] \times [1,2]$, those are obviously contained in two different dimensions, are they homeomorphic? I can't find any reason why they shouldn't be. Thank you.

Comment: "Dimension" is not something you can define for a general topological space.   The topology can't tell the difference in dimension.  On the other hand, nonempty open sets  $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ with the subspace topology are not homeomorphic for $m \neq n$, although I think this is not so easy to prove; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain#Consequences)

Comment: You [can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension) define a dimension on *any* topological space.

Answer (score 3):

Those particular sets aren't homeomorphic, but there's no reason sets "contained in two different dimensions" can't be. The plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ is homeomorphic to the plane $x+y+z=0$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$, or to the hemisphere $\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2 =1\text{ and }z>0\}$

An object $X$ being embedded in some larger space $Y$ is not a topological property of $Y$, so homeomorphism won't respect that.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{S}^2$ and $[0,1]\times [1,2]$ can not be homeomorphic, because one of them is retractable and the other one is not.

**Def**: A topological space is called **retractable**, if you can deform it continuously to a point (by staying inside the space and without making holes). More rigorously, it is called retractable, if there is no [homotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy) between the identity function and a constant function.